# .findfirst vba access2010 unbound form runtime error

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have the following VBA code to populate unbound fields in an unbound form in Access 2010 :

```
Private Sub Combo0_AfterUpdate()

Dim D As Database
Dim rsExp As Recordset
Dim Criteria As String

Set D = CurrentDb
Set rsExp = D.OpenRecordset("ExpAsset", DB_OPEN_DYNASET)

Criteria = "[serial_number]=" & [Combo0]

rsExp.FindFirst Criteria

Me!Name = rsExp("User")
Me!Type = rsExp("Type")
Me!MODEL = rsExp("Model")
Me!Notes = rsExp("Notes")
Me!Department = rsExp("Department")
Me!Status = rsExp("Status")

rsExp.Close

End Sub
```

I am getting error on this line rsExp.FindFirst Criteria runtime error 3077 Syntax error (Missing operator) in expression.

I have changed the code to Criteria = "[serial_number]=" & Str([Combo0]) but then i get runtime error 13 type mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give yourself an opportunity to examine the criteria you're asking `.FindFirst` to use.  It may not be what you expect.

```vb
Dim strCriteria As String
'strCriteria = "[serial_number]=" & Me.Combo0
' since serial_number is text, enclose the Combo0 value in quotes
' when you build strCriteria
strCriteria = "[serial_number]='" & Me.Combo0 & "'"
Debug.Print strCriteria
' or MsgBox strCriteria if you prefer
```

You can see the output from `Debug.Print` in the Immediate window.  Go there with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>

If `[serial_number]` is text data type, and `Debug.Print` gives you something like either of these, you have a problem.

```vb
[serial_number]=A0123
[serial_number]=
```

If that doesn't lead you to the solution tell us the data type of `[serial_number]` and the value of `Me.Combo0` when you encounter the error.

Comment: Serial_number is a Text data type as we have alpha numeric serial numbers for our equipment like laptops, hotspots, GPS Etc.

Comment: Excellent.  See whether the revised answer is enough to fix you up.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I kept my old code, didn't change a thing except just to return a string criteria added the 2 apostrophes ('). This thing had been driving me crazy for a couple of days, thanks again.